# Is my Proxy Server config bad?

Tags: node.js, nginx, amazon-ec2

I've stumbled on a configuration that works by trial and error. But I can't tell if I'm doing something bad.
https://www.nginx.com/blog/setting-up-nginx/ I've used this guide to set up some files and folders but then altered it to make it work for node and port 3000.

This is my index.js file in folder /home/ubuntu/server

```
var http=require('http');

var server=http.createServer(function(req,res){
    res.end('tudor');
});

server.on('listening',function(){
    console.log('ok, server is running');
});

server.listen(3000);
index.js (END)
```

/etc/nginx/conf.d$ less server1.conf

```
server {
    root /home/ubuntu/public_html;

    location /application1 {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080/sampleApp;
    }

    location /images {          
        root /home/ubuntu/data; 
    }

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
    }

}
```

Is there anything wrong with this?

Comment: The statement `root /home/ubuntu/public_html;` seems to have no purpose.

Comment: Yes, but it's nothing that is a problem either. I used it because it was part of the old tutorial. I'm more worried about exposing the 80 port directly, or something like that which I don't understand well.